# Order after Salat?

Tags: salat, dua, prayer-timings

After *salat* muslims can do Thikr (33,33,34), Dua, and recite the Qur'an.

Is there a specific order (ie. of Dua, Thikr, Qur'an) given in any of the Madhabs for these?

Is there a 'correct' order, or are there different opinions, or is there leeway so that muslims can do things in whichever order they please?

Answer (score 0):

That's all up to you, whether you want Zekr after Salat or reading Quran. There's no order enforcement for your case.

Comment: According to which Scholar of which Madhab?